# how can we create n nodes of different references?

Tags: java

I have to create a project of data management of linked list(singly) i am confused on how can we create nodes of different references. As far as I know node is a object and to create a object we simply write (`classname ref = new constructor()`). now what I want to do is that I want to save data of first employee

In one node, second employee data on second node....and nth employee data on nth node. here is my problem that for second node I need to write syntax again to create second node and if I want to save n records of employee how can I write n syntax's of nodes. I know that a node contains two things which are data and address of second node. For Example:

```
class node {
    String data ; 
    node next;
    node(String data , node a ){
        this.data = data;
        next = a ;
    }
}
main(){         
    node n1 = new node("a",n2); 
    node n2 = new node("b",null);
    till nth.
        /*well i thought that if i could loop this so that it automatically 
         *create nodes but even if i did that then the data will be saved on same 
         reference/address */
}
```

hope i clarified my problem as much as you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate and hold on to a reference to the node that you created in the last iteration.

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

Node previousNode = null;
for (String datum : data)
{
    previousNode = new Node(datum, previousNode);
}
//previousNode now contains a reference to the last node (C)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create several differently-named variables in a loop. You can however put them in a list, or -- since you're essentially creating a linked list -- you may just want to keep the last-created node and iterate over the nested nodes when you need to perform any action on them.

This will give you the last Node in variable n:

```
Node n;
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", ...).forEach(s -> n = new Node(s, n));
```

This will give you a list of Nodes:

```
Node n;
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", ...)) {
  n = new Node(s, n);
  nodes.add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Algorithm

1. Create a `head` and `ref` that will hold the start of your List
2. Iterate over your list. For each iteration create assign it to `head.next = newNode`
3. Advance `head` => `head = head.next`
4. Repeat 2 & 3 as necessary
5. Your list will be in `ref` as its head

## Code

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
Node head = new Node(list.get(0), null);
Node ref = head;

for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
  head.next = new Node(list.get(i), null);
  head = head.next;
}

// Your list is ready, you can iterate through it as such
while (ref != null) {
  System.out.println(ref.data);
  ref = ref.next;
}
```